# simple SQL query

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

Student.Name; Student.RollNum; Student.Email; Student.Courses; Student.Birthday;
Course.ID ; Course.Name; Course.Instructor

Now heres my proposed DB design:  two tables=> Students, Courses
Student.ID is a new field added-> primary unique key for Students table

Now what would be the query to retrieve all the courses taken by John Doe (whose Student.ID=1234) ??

I need the names of the courses, not the IDs.

Comment: Your table design is flawed. You have all of the courses listed together in a single column (Student.Courses), and you can't right portable sql that will use individual items from that column. You need a third table (Enrollments) that pairs a studentID with a courseID (and possibly a year/term)

Answer (score 2):

I would design it with 3 tables:

```
Students - ID; Name; RollNum; Email; Birthday;
Courses - ID; Name; Instructor
Students_Courses - a join table between the students and the courses
```

Then you can do the following

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Students_Courses sc
    ON s.id = sc.studentId
INNER JOIN Courses c
    ON sc.course_id = c.courseid
WHERE s.id = 1234
```

OR if you don't want any of the student info, you can shorten the query to:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM Students_Courses sc
INNER JOIN Courses c
    ON sc.course_id = c.courseid
WHERE sc.studentId = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a **third table** to join Students and Courses.  This would allow many courses to be taken by many students.  The table would store the StudentId and CourseId.  You could then achieve the results you want with the following query:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.CourseName
FROM Courses c
    INNER JOIN StudentCourse sc
     ON c.CourseId = sc.CourseId
WHERE sc.StudentId = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Homework?
You need a new table, let's say StudentsCourses that represents the relation between a student and the courses he attends. You need to add a CourseId to the Course table. So the StudentsCourses is defined as:

```
StudentCourses(StudentId, CourseId)
```

At this point, you obtain the attended courses with a join:

```
SELECT Courses.*
FROM Courses JOIN StudentsCourses sc ON sc.CourseId = Courses.CourseId
WHERE sc.StudenId = [DesideredStudentId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is flawed. You have all of the courses listed together in a single column (Student.Courses), and you can't right portable sql that will use individual items from that column. You need a third table (Enrollments) that pairs a studentID with a courseID (and possibly a year/term).

But assuming you add this table, the sql would look something like this:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM Enrollments e
INNER JOIN Courses c on c.ID = e.CourseID
WHERE e.StudentID = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you would need a third table that holds the courses taken by each student, could be as simple as a 2 column table(StudentId, CourseId) and the query would be

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM Students as s
JOIN CoursesTaken as t on t.StudentId = s.Id
JOIN Courses as c on c.id = t.CourseId
WHERE s.Id = 1234
```